# Svelte can't find image

Tags: html, svelte, sveltekit, svelte-component

I am trying add an local image on my svelte project. But it's giving 404 error. How can i fix it?

``

```
<script>
    const src = './image/Banner.png'
</script>

<main>
    <header>
        <div class="Banner">
            <div class="banner-img">
                <img src="{src}" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="banner-text"></div>
        </div>
    </header>
</main>
```

``

This the error

> [23:51:25] 404 ─ 0.20ms ─ /image/Banner.png

I am trying add an local image on my svelte project. But it's giving 404 error`your text`

Comment: Where did you place your folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your image inside **/public** folder or subfolder (/public/assets/ in my example ) and call it  in src atribute like this:

```
<img src="assets/pdf_icon.gif" alt="Pdf">
```

Comment: I don't have the public folder already created, so if i am to create public folder, where should it reside?

inside src folder or where?

Comment: @Abdulraheem public folder is located parallel to the src folder

Answer (score 0):

What about importing the image like this?

```
<script>
    import bannerImg from "$lib/Banner.png"; // The href of the image
</script>

<main>
    <header>
        <div class="Banner">
            <div class="banner-img">
                <img src={bannerImg} alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="banner-text"></div>
        </div>
    </header>
</main>
```

You might also want to set up an alias in kit.alias in your svelte.config.js file, like this:

```js
kit: {
  ...
  alias: {
    ...
    $img: "src/lib/imgs"
  },
  ...
}
```

And then you can put it in an extra folder called imgs, and access it like this:

```
<script>
    import bannerImg from "$img/Banner.png";
</script>
```